# call procedure with out parameters in hibernate3

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I work with hibernate3 and didn't use JPA
I have a procedure in oracle which return 2 out parameter
For test I execute this procedure in oracle with this query.

```
declare

req_type  number;
req_seq  number;

begin

insert_req(1111,req_type,req_seq);
dbms_output.put_line('req_type='||req_type);
dbms_output.put_line('req_seq='||req_seq);
end;
```

Now I want to call this procedure using hibernate

I try with native query without success using this code :

```
public void insertReq(String numEmp) {

                    int req_type  ;
                    int req_seq;


                    String sql = " insert_req(1111,:in1,:in2) ";
                    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
                    query.setParameter("in1", req_type); 
                    query.setParameter("in2", req_seq); 
                    List results = query.list();

                    System.out.println(req_type);
                    System.out.println(req_seq);

                    }
```

when I have a function I can run it using hibernate using this code as an example :

```
public void insertOrder(String numEmp) {

            String query = "call  insert_order(" + numEmp + ",50)";


            SQLQuery sqlQuery = this.getSession().createSQLQuery(query);
            sqlQuery.executeUpdate();

        }
```

but the problem is how to call procedure with 2 out parameter using hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use CallableStatement and registerOutParameter. 
you can get a connection from your hibernate session and create the callablestatement.
hibernate does not provide a mecanism to deal with this (at least as i know).
i hope that helps.

Comment: thank you for your response,
I solve my problem using CallableStatement and registerOutParameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know.

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();

Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
session.doWork(new Work() {

    @Override
    public void execute(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        // do something useful
        try (CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("{call my_sp()}")) {
            stmt.execute();
        }
    }
});

em.close();
```

Best regards.